# Convert Date from one format to another

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

I trying to convert date from one format to another. But the **date** in the below code  is coming as nil. Can you guys help me out below is the code.

```
   func eventTimeDate() -> Date {
        let dtf = DateFormatter()
        dtf.timeZone = TimeZone.current
        dtf.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z" 

        /// "2020-05-28 00:20:00 GMT+5:30"   
        let stringDate = dtf.string(from: self)

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss z"

        /// nil
        let date = dateFormatter.date(from: stringDate)

        return date!
    }
```

Comment: That makes no sense because a  `Date` has no format. You probably want to start with a *string*, convert it to a date, and then back to a string (with a different format).

Comment: The date is nil because your `stringDate` doesn't match the format of the actual format you expect (expecting with `/`, but you're giving it a string with `-`). But what are you actually doing? Date is Date - it's an object. You can apply any formatting to it when you need to convert it. It's meaningless to say that date object itself has formatting

Comment: @MartinR The requirement for me is to convert to Date from one formatter to Date of different format. I don't want to return a string format

Comment: A `Date` is an absolute value in time (represented internally as number of seconds since January 1, 2000. A `Date`  HAS NO FORMAT.

Comment: Everyone else already said this, but a Date doesn't have a format. What has a format is when you convert it to a string.

Comment: ok but how to convert a String of format "2020-05-28 00:20:00 GMT+5:30"  to  Date 2020/05/28 00:20:00 GMT+5:30

Comment: You can convert it to a STRING that says "2020/05/28 00:20:00 GMT+5:30" but the DATE object will always be "2020-05-28 00:20:00 GMT+5:30"

Answer (score 0):

If you need to convert from one formatted date string to another formatted date string, you can use two `DateFormatter`s: one - an input formatter to convert a String to an intermediary `Date` object, and then - using an output formatter - convert from Date to String.

```
func reFormat(from dateStr: String) -> String? {
  let fromFormatter = DateFormatter()
  fromFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"

  let toFormatter = DateFormatter()
  toFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss z"

  guard let date = fromFormatter.date(from: dateStr) else { return nil }

  return toFormatter.string(from: date)
}
```

If you just need to return a `Date` object, then it's a simpler function using just one `DateFormatter`:

```
func toDate(from dateStr: String) -> Date? {
  let formatter = DateFormatter()
  formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z"

  return formatter.date(from: dateStr)
}
```

`Date` object itself has no formatting - it's a pure representation of a date & time, which you can convert to/from using different formatters.

Comment: The above code returns a string.. i would require a date. the line toFormatter.string(date) returns a string

Comment: Did you not say in your comment that you need to convert one formatted string to a another formatted string? @user578386

Comment: In my question. I have mentioned i require a date..and also my function return type is of type date...I don't require a string

Comment: Ok, so you want your function to return a Date, and the input being a formatted String? @user578386

Comment: /// "2020-05-28 00:20:00 GMT+5:30"   would be my input string i want it to be date object  2020/05/28 00:20:00 GMT+5:30

Comment: Ok, but that's exactly what a DateFormatter does. I amended the answer. @user578386

Comment: Returns nil. This is exaclty what i have written in my question

Comment: @user578386 - what's your input string?

Comment: "2020-05-28 00:20:00 GMT+5:30"

Comment: @user578386 - both functions work for me with this date string

Answer (score 0):

A swift class **Date** has no format.

In your code your **stringDate** is in "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z" format. If you need to convert **String** to **Date** you must use the same format otherwise it will return nil.

If you want to change a format of a string then first convert it to a Swift '**Date**' then again convert it to a string with the use of new Formatter.

```
func eventTimeDate(dateString : String, currentFormat : String, newFormat : String) -> String? {
    let currentDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    currentDateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: Calendar.Identifier.gregorian)
    currentDateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_IN")
    currentDateFormatter.dateFormat = currentFormat
    let date = currentDateFormatter.date(from: dateString)

    let newDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    newDateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: Calendar.Identifier.gregorian)
    newDateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_IN")
    newDateFormatter.dateFormat = newFormat
    if let date = date {
        let newDateString = newDateFormatter.string(from: date)
        return newDateString
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have three problems in your code. First when parsing a fixed date format you should always set the date formatter's locale to "en_US_POSIX". Second you need to escape the GMT of your date string. Last but not least important you need to fix your timezone string which it is missing the leading zero for your timezone hour:

```
let dateStr = "2020-05-28 00:20:00 GMT+5:30"
let formatter = DateFormatter()
// set the date formatter's locale to "en_US_POSIX"
formatter.locale = .init(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
// escape the GMT of your date string
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z"
// add the leading zero for your timezone hour
let string = dateStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "(GMT[+-])(\\d:)", with: "$10$2", options: .regularExpression)
if let date = formatter.date(from: string) {
    print(date)  // "2020-05-27 18:50:00 +0000\n"
}
```