# Swift: Convert Array of String dates into Formatted String dates

Tags: swift, date, date-formatting

So I have an array of dates that are already formatted as strings. But I want to further format it. What I have currently prints me nil. I want to be able to convert it into something like "June, 23, 2020" or "June-23", etc. What am I missing?

```
let dates = ["2020-06-23", "2021-06-24", "2022-06-25", "2020-06-26", "2020-06-29"]

for i in dates {
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: i)
print(date)
}
```

Comment: You don't need a DateFormatter for that purpose. If the given dates have a fixed format then you can just strip the first 8 characters.

Comment: But what if I want to convert it to something like "June - 23" or "June, 23"

Comment: That is not what you said: “I want to further format it by getting rid of the years and months.” – `dateFormatter.date(from: i)` fails because the strings do not match the "dd" format.

Comment: Hey Martin, sorry about that. This was just an example, stripping first 8 characters won't help me since I'm dealing with years of data. For some, I would want to format it as days of weeks, some months, and some in years.

Comment: Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62050294/convert-date-from-one-format-to-another

Comment: I see questions like this so often, I wrote a little post just about it. The solution is always the same, and it's always simple: don't store dates as strings. I suggest you check it out: [Dates aren't Strings.](https://github.com/amomchilov/Blog/blob/master/Dates%20aren't%20Strings.md)

Comment: Hey Alexander, even if the API stores the date as a string? When making the call, we can still parse it as type Date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you get the right format. Then you can change it.

You can use

```
let dates = ["2020-06-23", "2021-06-24", "2022-06-25", "2020-06-26", "2020-06-29"]

//create an empty array of dates
var datesFormated = [Date]()

let initialDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
initialDateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

for i in dates {
    let date = initialDateFormatter.date(from: i)!
    //but you have to make sure that the date format of the strings match the date formatter, otherwise it will crash
    
    datesFormated.append(date)
}

//then change the format to the one you need
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, yyyy"

for date in datesFormated {
    
    let date = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    
    print(date)
```

}

Output would be

```
Jun 23, 2020
Jun 24, 2021
Jun 25, 2022
Jun 26, 2020
Jun 29, 2020
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
let dates = ["2020-06-23", "2021-06-24", "2022-06-25", "2020-06-26", "2020-06-29"]
var datesFormated = [Date]()

let initialDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
initialDateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM d, yyyy"

dates.forEach {
    datesFormated.append( initialDateFormatter.date(from: $0)! )
}

datesFormated.forEach {
    print(dateFormatter.string(from: $0))
}
```

Output:

```
Jun 23, 2020
Jun 24, 2021
Jun 25, 2022
Jun 26, 2020
Jun 29, 2020
```

Answer (score 1):

I was writing this as you posted your answer, but I'll post anyway as there's a slight difference in approaches.

I suggest using both `DateFormatter.date(from: string)` AND `DateFormatter.string(from: date)`.  In other words, build *two* distinct date formatters: one to read in your date in "yyyy-MM-DD" format, and another to make a string in a different format.  You can then change each of the formatters as needed, or even have a method wrapping this code where you can insert different formatters or format strings, making it flexible if you want to change formats.

Also, there's no need to instance a new formatter every time you go through the loop.

```
    let dates = ["2020-06-23", "2021-06-24", "2022-06-25", "2020-06-26", "2020-06-29"]
    
    // use this formatter to read in dates from initial strings
    let originalDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    originalDateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    
    // use this formatter to generate new strings from dates
    let newDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    newDateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM d" // or choose whatever new string format you want
    
    for i in dates {
        if let date: Date = originalDateFormatter.date(from: i) {
            let dateInNewStringFormat: String = newDateFormatter.string(from: date)
            print(dateInNewStringFormat) // prints as "June 23"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, initializing `DateFormatter` on every iteration is very wasteful. Make it constant or static, and only change format when needed.
Secondly, when working with DateFormatter, you should always think of it as *transformation* where date to string, or vice versa, but you cannot transform one string to another directly. In your case, you need:

```
string > date > string
```

So basic code would look like this:

```
let dates = ["2020-06-23", "2021-06-24", "2022-06-25", "2020-06-26", "2020-06-29"]
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

for i in dates {

    // string > date
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd"
    guard let fromDate = dateFormatter.date(from: i) else {
         // not a valid date, skip
         continue
    }
 
    // date > string
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM, YYYY" // or whatever you need
    let toDate = dateFormatter.string(from: fromDate)
    print(toDate)
}
```

But also, if you have this same formatting in multiple places in your code, it's best to create an extension:

```
extension Date {

    static let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

    // If you are dealing with the same date as input often, you can do this:
    init?(fromDateOnlyString: String) {
         Date.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd"
         guard let date = Date.dateFormatter.date(from: fromDateOnlyString) else {
            return nil
        }

        self = date
    }

    // If you need the same output format often, you can do this:
    func toMyDesiredFormat() -> String {
        Date.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM, YYYY" // Or whatever you need
        return Date.dateFormatter.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

And you use this extension like this:

```
for i in dates {
    guard let fromDate = Date(fromDateOnlyString: i) else {
        // not a valid date, skip
        continue
    }
    let toDate = fromDate.toMyDesiredFormat()
    print(toDate)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. You have you first convert it into Dates then convert those Dates into Formatted strings again. I had the format for the initial dateFormatter wrong as "dd".

```
let dates = ["2020-06-23", "2020-06-24", "2020-06-25", "2020-06-26", "2020-06-29"]
var formattedDates = [Date]()

for i in dates {
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: i) {
formattedDates.append(date)
  }
}

print(formattedDates)          //prints [2020-06-23 04:00:00 +0000, 2020-06-24 04:00:00 +0000, 2020-06-25 04:00:00 +0000, 2020-06-26 04:00:00 +0000, 2020-06-29 04:00:00 +0000]
```

Comment: Don’t create a new DateFormatter instance for each iteration of the loop, create only one and reuse it.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Code is definitely a lot cleaner now! :)